# Okular installation error

Tags: okular

error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Ensure prerequisites for "okular" are available (cannot install prerequisite "kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20": no snap revision available as specified)

I am getting this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the apt version instead of the snap version.

The first command removes the snap version, if installed, and the second installs okular with apt.

```
sudo snap remove okular
sudo apt install okular
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have the kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20 package, you just need to install it, open a terminal and do this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20
```

follow the prompt and you should be good